# Plotting subplots in a figure automatically for each column of matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

For example let's say I have a following matrix (<9x6 double>) with a colheaders(<1x6 cell>).

```
 Matrix =

   226.7431   14.7437   14.9417   14.1000   14.5000       66.0590   
   226.7500   14.6582   14.8250       NaN   14.2000       66.7740   
   226.7569   14.3590   14.6067       NaN   13.9000       68.4897   
   226.7639   14.2702   14.5717   13.4000   13.8000       68.2487   
   226.7708   14.2555   14.6000       NaN   14.0000       NaN        
   226.7778   14.1605   14.5967       NaN   13.9000       NaN      
   226.7847   14.0320   14.4567   12.9000   13.6000       68.8272   
   226.7917   13.8422   14.2733       NaN   13.4000       69.6392   
   226.7986   13.6585   14.1169       NaN   13.1000       69.8048
```

I want to plot first column of matrix on x-axis and the rest on y-axis in a matlab figure with subplots (let's say 3 in one figure). Manually I can do something like this a figure and so on.

```
figure
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(Matrix(:,1),Matrix(:,2),'ro'); grid on; box on; xlabel('A');ylabel('B')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(Matrix(:,1),Matrix(:,3),'bo'); grid on; box on; xlabel('A');ylabel('C')
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(Matrix(:,1),Matrix(:,4),'go'); grid on; box on; xlabel('A');ylabel('D')
and so on.....
......
......
```

Now here start a tricky part in which I required help from experts like you guys. I do not want to do manual plotting for my matrix as it consists on 200 columns. So what I want to do a automatic plotting of matrix, so that it plot every column of matrix in subplots. But 200 subplot can not come in one figures, so it start automatically a new figure after  subplots limit(let's say 3). Beside I also need to define 'xlabel, ylabel,legend' automatically with a header file 'colheaders'. Is it possible?

Comment: @ F.Dernoncourt: I can do manual plot but I want to use some sort of 'for loop' to do automatic plotting in 5 to 10 lines. If I do manual plot it takes a lot of time and 200 lines at least for 200 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = rand(10, 200);
myYLabel = char(64+randi(26, 200, 1));

nrows = 3;
ncols = 2;
for ii = 1:size(x, 2)
    if nrows*ncols-mod(-ii, nrows*ncols) == 1
        figure;
    end
    subplot(nrows, ncols, nrows*ncols-mod(-ii, nrows*ncols));
    plot(x(:, ii));
    ylabel(myYLabel(ii, :));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an easy for-loop task.

I assume you know before how much subplots you want in each figure (let's say 3).

```
A = yourdatamatrix;   
header = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'C'}, {'D'}, {'E'}, {'F'}];
n = 6 %number of columns

i_figure = 1;


for ii=1:3:n-3
    figure(ii)
    subplot(3,1,1)
    plot(A(:,1),A(:,ii+1),'ro'); grid on; box on; xlabel(header(1));ylabel(header(ii+1))
    subplot(3,1,2)
    plot(A(:,1),A(:,ii+2),'bo'); grid on; box on; xlabel(header(1));ylabel(header(ii+2))
    subplot(3,1,3)
    plot(A(:,1),A(:,ii+3),'go'); grid on; box on; xlabel(header(1));ylabel(header(ii+3))
end
```

I assume also you don't care about your figure number, otherwise just implement another counter.
Also be aware that the number of your columns+1 is divisible by 3.