# Looping through columns to make subplots

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have an spectral absorbance matrix in `xls` format which has column 1 as wavelength, and columns 2:3 as the associated absorbance spectra for particles from depth1 in water column. 2:3 are duplicates so they have to be plotted together. Next i have columns 4:5  as once again duplicate absorbance spectra for particles from depth2 in water column. Then data for depth3, depth4 etc. The matrix is 1001 rows by 13 columns.

I would like have 3 subplots (depth1, depth2 and depth3) in one figure with each subplot holding the 2 duplicate spectra of each depth.

I tried to follow the excellent responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033591/plotting-subplots-in-a-figure-automatically-for-each-column-of-matrix/19033996#19033996) but this gives me one line per subplot but i want to plot two lines (duplicate spectra). So I did the following and it works but I can only get 3 subplots:

```
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('ANACONDAS2010-ST1.xls');
legendCell=cellstr(txt);
figure
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,2:3),'r');grid on; box on; xlabel('Wavelength'), ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(2:3)),legend boxoff 

subplot(3,1,2)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,4:5),'b');grid on; box on; xlabel('Wavelength'),   ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(4:5)), legend boxoff 

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,6:7),'g');grid on; box on; xlabel('Wavelength'),  ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(6:7)), legend boxoff  

title('STATION 1','fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
```

But as you can see this gives me only 1 figure with 3 subplots and the rest od the depths (d4, d5, d6) remain unplotted as i havent been able to specifiy them,

Because my script is long and cumbersome I would have liked to run this through a loop but I couldn't figure out how to do it in spite of battling with the code provided in the 2nd answer which I kind of understood unlike the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**
**Inserted version V2 of the code**

Version V2 of the code allows displaying unlimited pairs of data, also it is even simpler than V1.

```
% Generation of example data
num=1:33;
number_of_data_colums=14;
num=[num' rand(length(num),number_of_data_colums)];
% Generation of legend string
for i=1:number_of_data_colums
   legendCell{i}=['Absor. ' num2str(i)];
end
% Get the size of data to be plotted (columns from 2 to ...)
[r,c]=size(num);
n_data=floor((c-1)/2);
% Define the number of data to be plotted in each subplt
data_x_plot=2;
% Consistency check: if the number of column data is not even generate an
% error message and exit
if(n_data*2 ~= (c-1))
   error('Number of data columns is not even')
else
% Define the number of subplot of each figure
n_sub_plot=3;
% Subplot and figure counters
s_plot_cnt=1;
fig_cnt=1;
% Create the first figure
figure
% External loop on figures
for i=2:2:n_data*2
% If three subplot have been added to a figure, open a new figure
   if(s_plot_cnt == 4)
% The Title is assigne to the first subplot of each figure   
      title(ax(fig_cnt,1),['STATION ' num2str(fig_cnt)],'fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
      s_plot_cnt=1;
      fig_cnt=fig_cnt+1;
      figure
   end
      ax(fig_cnt,s_plot_cnt)=subplot(n_sub_plot,1,s_plot_cnt);
% The indices of columns to be plotted are computed automatically
      plot(num(:,1), num(:,i:i+1));
      grid on;
      box on;
      xlabel('Wavelength')
      ylabel('Absorbance')
% add legend      
      legend(legendCell(i-1:i),-1)
% Increment subplot's counter      
      s_plot_cnt=s_plot_cnt+1;
%       legend boxoff
   end
end
% Add the last title
title(ax(fig_cnt,1),['STATION ' num2str(fig_cnt)],'fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
```

**Previous answer and**
**Version V1 of the code**

I'm not sure I've understood your question, nevertheless, if you have 6 pairs of data and you want 3 subplot, you need 2 figures.

I've modified your original script in order to automatically determine the number of figure you need, generate the subplots and plot 2 set of data in each of them.

**Updated code - now with legends**

```
% Generation of example data
num=1:33;
num=[num' rand(length(num),12)];
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    UPDATED CODE STARS HERE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Generation of legend string
legendCell{1}='Wavel';
for i=2:13
   legendCell{i}=['Absor. ' num2str(i)];
end
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    UPDATED CODE ENDS HERE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Get the size of data to be plotted
[r,c]=size(num);
% Define the number of data to be plotted in each subplt
data_x_plot=2;
% Define the number of subplot of each figure
n_sub_plot=3;
% Evaluate the number of figures to be created
n_fig=(c-1)/(data_x_plot*n_sub_plot);
% Define the index of data columns
idx=[2:2:c-1];
idx=reshape(idx,n_sub_plot,data_x_plot)';
% External loop on figures
for i=1:n_fig
   figure
% Internal loop on subplots   
   for j=1:n_sub_plot
% The subplot indices are computed automatically
      ax(i,j)=subplot(n_sub_plot,1,j);
% The indices of columns to be plotted are computed automatically
      plot(num(:,1), num(:,idx(i,j):idx(i,j)+1));
      grid on;
      box on;
      xlabel('Wavelength')
      ylabel('Absorbance')
% add legend      
      legend(legendCell(idx(i,j):idx(i,j)+1),-1)
%       legend boxoff
   end
% The Title is assigne to the first subplot of each figure   
   title(ax(i,1),['STATION ' num2str(i)],'fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
end
```

Given a set of 12 columns of data, this is the output:

[image]

[image]

**Updated graphs, with legends**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very good answer.  I was about to write an answer, but I was so confused with the wording that I just gave up lol. +1.

Comment: Thank you very much - I am so grateful Raffa. I had one favor to ask - how can i add a legend to each subplot with the legend being the header of each column ie the first row. Also my apologies for not having stated the problem clearly.

Comment: To add a legend, use the `legend` function; you already did it in the code you posted. I've commneted it since I did not have the Excel from which to read it. Nevertheless, I've updated the code in my answer (I needed to generate some text);  adding `-1` in the call to `legend` allows you to have the legend box aside the graph (ref. to MatLab help for more informations). I've also updated the images in the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Raffa I am truly grateful as not only did i get my code but i actually learned to use loops for the first time ever!!! Could you just clarify one thing which caused me a bit of confusion: in the line 'idx=reshape(idx,n_sub_plot,data_x_plot)' - i know you used the transpose sign but i couldnt understand the logic behind the line. Sorry!

Comment: sorry to bother you Raffa but i hit a snag when i had 10 columns and i suspect it is because now n_fig becomes 1.6667. I dont know how to fix that as i then get an error: >> idx=reshape(idx,n_sub_plot,data_x_plot)'
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change

Comment: Hello @fatima55! I've inserted the Version V2 of the code, now it can plot any number of pairs of data in three subplots for each figure. With respect to the use of the transpose sign in V1, it was only to simplify (to me) the handling of the indeces: you can remove it and swap "i" and "j" in the call to `plot`. Nevertheless, in V2 is not longer used. Hope V2 could answer your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [Hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to retain current plot when adding new plots.
So your code should be like this:

```
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('ANACONDAS2010-ST1.xls');
legendCell=cellstr(txt);
figure
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,2),'r');grid on;
hold on;
plot(num(:,1), num(:,3),'m');
box on; xlabel('Wavelength'), ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(2:3)),legend boxoff 

subplot(3,1,2)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,4),'b');
hold on;
plot(num(:,1), num(:,5),'c');
grid on; box on; xlabel('Wavelength'),   ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(4:5)), legend boxoff 

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(num(:,1), num(:,6),'g');
hold on;
plot(num(:,1), num(:,7),'k');
grid on; box on; xlabel('Wavelength'),  ylabel('Absorbance'),legend(legendCell(6:7)), legend boxoff  

title('STATION 1','fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
```

Comment: In this case, `hold on` would produce the same thing as what the OP did.  If you plot a matrix of values for the vertical axis, each column would represent a separate trace.  What you're doing is plotting each column individually with `hold on` to separate the traces.  As such, your code would do the same thing as what the OP has.

Comment: Hi rayryeng i have improved the clarity of my comment as i know it was not good.